# How to check if the set column contains value in spring data jpa

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

With spring data jpa 2.4.1, I try to check if the column "leader_ids" contains my expected value.

I tried used `member of` `@Query(value = "select re from RequestEntity re where ?1 member of re.leaderIds")` but the project failed to start cause by

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.iqax.iam.request.RequestRepository.findByLeaderIds(java.lang.String)!
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Also  I tried used `@Query(value = "select re from RequestEntity re join re.leaderIds lid where lid = ?1")` but still same error as above

I tried add `nativeQuery = true` and it said

```
java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'leader_ids' at line 1
```

Also I tried directly use Set as parameters but it failed like below

```
Parameter value [GENTLE.CHEN] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]
```

Finally I tried use `containing` but it said

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown collection expression type [org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath]
```

Any idea pls? Many thanks for your help.

BTW, I am using the convert like below

```
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Set<String> set) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(set)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return String.join(",", set);
        }
    }
 public Set<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String joined) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(joined)) {
            return new HashSet<>();
        } else {
            return new HashSet<>(
                    Set.copyOf(
                            Arrays.asList(
                                    joined.split(",")
                            )
                    )
            );
        }
    }
```

So the value in fact exist in db is like this `A,B`

```
@Service
// List<RequestEntity> requestEntityList = requestRepository.findDistinctByLeaderIds(Collections.singleton(leaderId));
List<RequestEntity> requestEntityList = requestRepository.findDistinctByLeaderIdsContaining(Collections.singleton(leaderId));
//        List<RequestEntity> requestEntityList = requestRepository.findByLeaderIds(leaderId);
```

```
@Repository
//    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from request where ?1 member of leader_ids")
//    @Query(value = "select re from RequestEntity re where ?1 member of re.leaderIds")
//    @Query(value = "select re from RequestEntity re join re.leaderIds lid where lid = ?1")
//    List<RequestEntity> findDistinctByLeaderIdsContaining(Set<String> leaderIds);
    List<RequestEntity> findDistinctByLeaderIdsContaining(String leaderId);
//    List<RequestEntity> findByLeaderIds(String leaderId);
```

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej ```leader_ids``` is a set collection, can directly use ```=```?

Comment: No, only one table there.

Comment: I tried to use set<String> as parameter in repository, that is why I use ```Collections.singleton(leaderId)```, i also tried new a HashSet for it, but not works either.